# Can't connect to oracle db most of the times

Tags: java, oracle11g

Good evening everyone, I'm getting confused with some troubles I'm incurring opening a connection with my db. 
The code I've listed down, works fine establishing the connection at work, but at home it's working funny. I mean, at first I used my ip instead of localhost and it was working fine. After restarting my computer, I got the " The Network Adapter could not establish the connection" error, and after 1 hour of efforts and simply putting localhost instead of my ip, it magically started working again, but guess what. Just after another restart, again with the same error.
I'm using eclipse neon the latest version, tomcat 9.0 on windows 7 64 bit and
I have bitdefender as antivirus.
Can someone help me? I don't understand what's happening.

```
public class Connessione {
private String driver="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver";
private static Connection connessione;

private final String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL";
private final String userName="xxxxx";
private final String password="xxxxx";

public Connection getConnessione() {
    return connessione;
}

public Connessione() {
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        connessione= DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}

public boolean chiudiConnessione(){
    try {
        connessione.close();
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is ur exception?

Comment: "At work and home" - do you mean the db is on your local machine, like docker or Orale installed, or you are connecting to remote one? Secondly are you using any vpn, network configuration, when you start your work?

Comment: As I said, the exception is "The Network Adapter could not establish the connection" and of course after that everything I try is futile.
Since I'm testing things at home, the db is local hence localhost and I was using oracle db.
Anyway I changed my db to MySQL and it's working fine now.